# Using charset ISO-8859-1

Tags: jsf, encoding

I'm from Brazil and here we have lots of `à` `é` `ô` `ó` `ç`, etc in our words and it is a problem on my JSF project.

I have a `master.xhtml` as a template for all my pages and here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/assets/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <title>#{masterController.projectName}</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding-top: 60px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
            }
            .sidebar-nav {
                padding: 9px 0;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{loginController.isLoggedIn}">
            <ui:include src="../includes/top.xhtml"/>
        </ui:fragment>
        <ui:insert name="body" />
        <hr />
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{loginController.isLoggedIn}">
            <ui:include src="../includes/footer.xhtml" />
        </ui:fragment>
    </h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/assets/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

As you can see my xml encondig is correct as my `Content-Type` meta tag.

I'm using Eclipse and on my project Properties->Resources I've changed the `Text file encoding` to *ISO-8859-1*.

I have a label on my `login.xhtml` page that goes inside `master.xhtml` called Usuário (User), if I use the character `á`, and the word is wrong without it, I get this error:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: null source
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    java.util.EventObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:67)
    javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:69)
    javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:69)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:256)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:245)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
```

Taking the `á` away it works but as I said, in Portuguese it is necessary and I'm gonna use a lot of other characters with accent.

Comment: Possibly try UTF-8 instead of ISO 8859-1? I suspect it's more widely used (and therefore, more heavily tested).

Comment: Made the changes and same results

Comment: The weird thing is that it returns a error telling me I passed a illegal character to a method and I'm only changing the letter `a` to `á`, no methods evolved, in this case I'm using only `html`

Comment: This answer is not applicable for JSF 2.0, because it does not support h:head tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the old ISO-8859-1 charset, but the new UTF-8 charset. JSF uses **by default** UTF-8 already which is much better prepared for world domniation.

Change everything to UTF-8 and change your IDE settings to use UTF-8 everywhere. In Eclipse, the most important setting is *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*.

[image]

Then, enter "encoding" in the *type filter text* on the left top input field and re-apply the change to UTF-8 for all other settings as well.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)